# Having trouble with maven-javadoc-plugin aggregation

Tags: javadoc, aggregate, maven-javadoc-plugin

I have a Maven aggregate project with three child modules, so the project is like so:

Parent
  |
  |- ChildA
  |- ChildB
  |- ChildC

The classes use aggregation and inheritence: Parent lists the children as modules, and each Child specifies Parent as its parent. Each of the children calls maven-javadoc-plugin:jar to generate sculpted javadocs with specific files included in the javadocs, which works fine.

I want to invoke maven-javadoc-plugin:aggregate-jar in the Parent pom to generate a single javadoc folder with the combination of the children's sculpted javadocs, but it doesn't appear to be working. If I run javadoc:aggregate-jar in Project, it looks like it aggregates the task down to the child modules, which execute their own maven-javadoc-plugin anyway, and then nothing gets generated by Project itself. I've tried running several different options and using the now deprecated  tag to no avail. I've also tried created a fourth child dependent on the other three to use maven-javadoc-plugin's  option with, but that doesn't seem to be working. Frustrating everything is that there are next to no examples of how to use aggregate on the official Maven plugin page or in Google, which leads me to believe I'm just doing something wrong.

Has anyone ever tried to do something like this before and can offer any help on how to get it working? Thank you for any help.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404322/how-to-use-javadocaggregate-properly-in-multi-module-maven-project